# Neo4j assign rank based on user score

Tags: neo4j, neo4jphp

I have `student` node with marks. I need to display rank, username and marks. But I am storing username, marks in the database. I have tried following

```
MATCH (s:student) WHERE s.marks > 70 RETURN s.marks as marks, s.uasername as name ORDER BY s.marks DESC
```

Output is

```
    marks   |  name
-------------------------
    95         user1
    94         user2
    93         user3
    93         user4
```

So here i want rank 3 for both user3, user4.

```
    marks   |  name    | rank
--------------------------------
    95         user1      1
    94         user2      2
    93         user3      3
    93         user4      3
```

Any suggestion.

Comment: Cypher does not have a `rank` function. I guess the most easy way is to solve that problem on client side.

Answer (score 0):

You could group them by marks, then the order of your result represents the ranks.

```
MATCH (s:student) WHERE s.marks > 70 
RETURN s.marks as marks, colleect(s.username) as names 
ORDER BY s.marks DESC
```

Comment: I need to display the ranks of those particular users